# Is the given set closed under a certain topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $R$ be the set of real numbers with the topology for which $$\{[a, \infty)\ |\ a\in \mathbb{R}\}$$ forms a basis. Consider the subset $$S=\{(x, \sin x)\ |\ x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$of $R\times R$ with the subspace topology, where $R\times R$ is equipped with product topology. Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to S$ defined by $$\phi(x)=(x, \sin x).$$

Is the image of the interval $(0, \pi/2)$ under $\phi$ closed in $S$?

I want to show that this is not a closed set. Consequently, I tried to write it in terms of open subsets of the given basis but unable to do so. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: That thing Is not a subset of $S$

Comment: Is $R=\Bbb R{}$?

Comment: No. As a set $R=\mathbb{R}$, but to distinct it from the usual topology, the notation $R$ is used.

Comment: @Crostul Thank you for the comment. I have edited the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have edited the question.

Comment: What is the purpose of $S \times S$?

Comment: Yes. It was written erroneously.

Comment: Try looking at open neighborhoods of $(0,0) \in S$? [and note you still have $S \times S$ mentioned in the question, which I assume is still in error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the topology generated by {$[a,∞) | a∈\mathbb{R}$} every open set is is closed upwards- if $a$ is in the set and $b > a$ then $b$ is in the set. In the product topology, any set is generated by products of these sets, and a product of upwards-closed sets is upwards closed in the sence that if $(a_1,a_2)$ is in the set and $b_1 ≥ a_1$ and $b_2 ≥ a_2$ then $(b_1,b_2)$ is in the set. Which in turn means that any open set in the product topology has this property.

This carries over to the subspace topology on $S$. You can prove that your set isn't closed by proving that it's complement doesn't have this property.